# how to change nginx config file for angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, nginx, nginx-config

My angular application is  running  on nginx server. When I type `http://**.8.100.248:30749` it show nginx is running. (Showing default index.html). But my application is present in `html` folder  having folder name `test`. So my application present in  “html —> test—> index.html”;;

So when I type `http://**.8.100.248:30749/test/index.html` my application run on browser, but when I route from one page to another and `reload` my page it gives me `404`.

Nginx gives me 404 when I reload my angular routed page. So  I changed the nginx config but still not success

```
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    expires -1;
    add_header Pragma "no-cache";
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /test/index.html =404;
}
```

any update

Comment: Which URL gives you 404? And you say it works without reloading? However that would work. Isn't angular a single page application? Show some URLs please...

Comment: @DanFromGermany take a example on button click I open new component `http://**.8.100.248:30749/test/abc` it show  the content .but when I reload this it show 404

Comment: because `nginx` try to  find `index.html` inside the `abc` but there is not `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `root` to `/usr/share/nginx/html/test` on your config should solve your problem.

Comment: without using `try_files`

Comment: Maybe he does not want to change the root, but just use the `/test/` folder publicly.

Comment: @Joy you have to clearify what you actually want. Do you want the `/test/` folder to be part of the URL or not?

Answer (score 0):

In your config file add the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe fix indent of first line.